# Make Call and send SMS from Windows Phone 7 background app

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-process

Can I have some pointers on how can my "background app" make a call and send sms at some pre-defined number and predefined datetime.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

Windows Phone 7 does not support apps running in the background.

If you wanted to make a call or send an SMS from your app (while it was running [in the foreground]) you will need to use the [PhoneCallTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) or [SmsComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.smscomposetask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), respectively.
Note that these tasks don't actually make the call or send the SMS but prompt the user to be able to do so. One of the design intents of the platform is that the phone can't do something the user might not want it to, without the user knowing.